# Checking random number variable against Javascript array values for match, not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

For the sake of learning (I am very much a beginner), I am trying to write a function with that will generate random numbers according to three user inputed variables.  The user can input how many random numbers to generate

```
var count = 10;
```

which numbers to avoid generating (seperated by commas)

```
var doNotInclude = (document.getElementById("doNotIncludeInput").value).split(",");
```

and what the highest number possible should be

```
var highestNumber = 10;
```

In theory, if the user inputed "1,2" for the doNotInclude variable, the function should create an array containing those two numbers and then each time it generates a random number, check it against the array to see if the number it generated is one of the numbers it isn't supposed to generate.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.  It creates the array as it should which I verified via console.log(), but it will still generate the numbers it isn't supposed to.  Here's the full script:

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
var total = 0,
    average = 0,
    random = 0,
    count = parseInt(document.getElementById("countInput").value),
    doNotInclude = document.getElementById("doNotIncludeInput").value).split(","),
    highestNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("highestNumberInput").value);
    document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var proceed = false;
        for (random = Math.floor(((Math.random()) * (highestNumber + 1))); proceed == false;) {
            if (doNotInclude.indexOf(random)===-1) {
                proceed = true;
            }   
        }
        document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML + "<br />" + (i + 1) + ". " + random;
        total = total + random;
        if (i == (count - 1)) {
            total / count;
            document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Mean average = " + (Math.round(total / count));
        }
    }
}
```

The part that isn't working

```
if (doNotInclude.indexOf(random)===-1) {
                proceed = true;
            }
```

the indexOf function, is something I read about on here, but I guess I don't fully understand it.  By my understanding, it should check to see if any of the array values are the same as the random variable, and if not, then return "-1" and execute my code.  It doesn't seem to be doing that though.  I am super confused...would love some help.  Is it possible the array is storing the numbers as strings instead of integers, and that is the problem?

Comment: `proceed` is used for the loop that keeps generating random numbers until it gets one that does not match one from the array.  The for loop is set to keep going as long as `proceed == false`.  If the loop found that a generated number didn't match anything in the array, it would set `proceed = true`.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement doesn't work because of coercion.

```
===-1
```

The array `doNotInclude` contains strings, but `random` is an integer value, `===` always compares value and type both.

You should either use `==`. Or have the both types same.

Comment: I dud just find a way to convert my array into integers, but now it seems that the loop becomes infinite when i run it.  I have no idea why...

Comment: Your question was about a particular part not working. Why does it enter in a infinite loop, is a totally different question. I guess you need to debug your code.

Comment: @EricDavidSartor - This is the answer. The reason why you are getting the infinite loop is answered in http://stackoverflow.com/a/2270344/862479

Answer (score 0):

[Try this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2opodx9c/)

HTML

```
Count: <input id="countInput" value="10" /><br />
Do not include: <input id="doNotIncludeInput" value="0,1,2,3,4,5" /><br />
Highest Number: <input id="highestNumberInput" value="10" /><br />
<br />
<button type="button" id="button">Click to Run!</button><br />
<br />
Results:<br />
<div id="text1"></div>
```

Js

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    var currentCount = 0;
    var randomNumbers = [];
    var count = parseInt(document.getElementById("countInput").value);
    var doNotIncludeInput = document.getElementById("doNotIncludeInput").value.split(",");
    var highestNumberInput = parseInt(document.getElementById("highestNumberInput").value);
    var resultsElement = document.getElementById("text1");

    resultsElement.innerHTML = "";

    while(currentCount < count) {
        var random = -1;

        while(random === -1){
            random = Math.floor((Math.random()) * (highestNumberInput + 1));

            for(var i in doNotIncludeInput) {
                if(parseInt(doNotIncludeInput[i]) === random){
                    random = -1;
                }
            }

            if(random !== -1){
                randomNumbers.push(random);
            }
        }

        currentCount += 1;
    }

    resultsElement.innerHTML = randomNumbers.join(', ');
}
```